# Shutdown command history in terminal

Tags: command-line, shutdown, gnome-terminal, byobu

The default terminal in Ubuntu (13.04) preserves previous commands in an iterable list, even from session to session. Same with Byobu terminal.

But for some reason **sudo shutdown ....** is never preserved in this list.

Why is that? How can I change it so that the shutdown command is also saved, so I don't have type it each time? (I prefer using the terminal to the GUI.)

Answer (score 3):

More accurately, your shell (bash, by default) preserves the command history. It's not a function of the terminal app, gnu screen, or byobu. They all run bash, so they all share a bash history.

I don't see the behavior you're describing. My **sudo shutdown ...** commands seem to be preserved fine.

Some reasons you might not see a command in your bash history -

- when you enter a command with spaces at the very beginning of the line, it's not kept in the history (assuming your $HISTCONTROL contains "ignorespace" or "ignoreboth")
- the HISTIGNORE variable defines patterns to be excluded from the history. A cautious admin might add 'shutdown' as a string to exclude, to avoid accidentally shutting down a system with a mistaken history invocation.
- The history is written to disk (~/.bash_history) when the shell exits. If the shell is ended abnormally (e.g. segfault, power loss, etc) then your history for that session won't be saved. (During **shutdown** the shell is typically killed normally and writes its history.)

More details can be found here: [Bash Reference Manual: Bash History Facilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html)

Comment: OK - good info - I have been using Windows forever, just getting my feet wet with Linux the last few months, in my spare time. I will have to poke around. I don't start commands with a space that I know of. Maybe Ubuntu has shutdown defined in HISTIGNORE by default because they have the GUI, etc?

Comment: I thought they might have started that when I read your question, but my 13.04 workstation isn't doing that. I use the Ubuntu GNOME flavor distro, which is slightly different from a vanilla Unity install, but the differences between flavors rarely extend into the bash environment.